php Ajax $_FILES empty
I can't find how to get my ajax function to see the $_FILES array. This is a very common problem and I have read through many posts. Some of those say to load the form data. I tried (the commented out lines) that but don't know how to apply it. When displayed in the console, it just shows lists of functions so I must not being doing it correctly. When the form is submitted, it displays the $_POST array but shows the $_FILES array is empty. Would someone point out my mistakes, please?
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      LoadOptionTree();
    });

    function LoadOptionTree(){
        var dataArray = {};
        dataArray[0] = 'setup';

        $.ajax({
           type:  'POST',
           data:  dataArray ,
           async: false,
           url:"test_ajax.php",
           dataType: 'json',
           success:function(data) { 
              $( "#show_edit_form" ).html( data );
           }
        });
        return true;
    }

    function SaveAttributes(mode) {
        var dataArray = {};
        dataArray[0] = 'submit';         
        dataArray[1] = $('#upload' ).val();

    //var formData = new FormData($('#submitForm')[0]);
    // formData.append('upload', '1');
    // console.dir(formData);

        $.ajax({
          type:  'POST',
    //contentType: false, 
    //processData: false,               
          data:  dataArray ,
          async: false,
          url:"test_ajax.php",
          dataType: 'json',              
          success:function(data) {
             $( "#show_edit_form" ).html( data );
          }
        });
    } 
    </script>    
      
    <div id="show_edit_form"></div>


    /*********** ajax file ***********/
    switch ($_POST[0]) {
        
      case $_POST[0] == 'setup':       
          $arry = '';     
          $arry .= '<div>Upload: <input type="file" id="upload" name="filename"></div>';
          $arry .= '<div class="button"><input type="submit" name="Save Changes" value="Save Changes" id="save_changes" enctype="multipart/form-data" onclick="javascript:return SaveAttributes(\'normal\')"></div>';

          echo json_encode($arry);
          return;
          
      break;

      case $_POST[0] == 'submit':       
          echo json_encode('POST = ' . print_r($_POST, true) . ' FILES = ' . print_r($_FILES, true));
          return;
      break;              
    }   
           
     


You need to use FormData to upload a file with AJAX. You have that code commented out.

As mentioned, I don't know what to do with it. If I uncomment it, the files array is still empty. Do I need to pass it somehow?
